# What set up to use for API and Database

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api

So I'm developing a user based booking system and I want a database and API which I can write myself.
I was just wonder what plan I would go about using on Azure? 
The API will only be queried by 1 front end web app and will serve to do some of the logic which the web app does not do.
or instead of using azure do you guys think I should use another service? I was hoping to develop everything in ASP.net web API using mysql or sqllite.

Comment: I've already had a look and it seems mobile app would be the plan to go?\

Comment: There is no specific plan to choose; this is completely up to you, and you have many options (ranging from Web App service all the way to Virtual Machines, and any mix of the above). asp.net will run anywhere (even a Linux VM, with proper setup). MySQL will not. Each option has its advantages, and there's really no way to give you a "correct" answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say use whichever language you are most comfortable with, if that is C# then .NET and Azure would be the way to go, otherwise you could use Rails, Node or PHP on Heroku just as well. There is really no right answer it's whatever you feel will work best. For a simple api you can also use Firebase or Parse with almost no code.

Comment: I guess another question would be, is it better practice to host it on a Web app azure service or the VM?

Comment: That depends on how much money you are willing to spend and what additional services you need to run. If it's just a web api and sql you will be fine with a web app in a shared hosting environment. If you need the flexibility of your own server to modify IIS settings and run other services, you would go with a VPS. It comes down to what you need, not 'best practice'

Comment: okay, thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

If you want speed, you can take a look to [Azure Mobile Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-windows-store-dotnet-get-started/). It's a nice way to get a backend quickly up and running and you can use the .NET Backend, who it's based on ASP.NET Web Api and SQL Server.

If you want to do it yourself from scratch, ASP.NET Web Api and SQL Server through a web app could be fine for start. In a future, if you can need to personalize or customize something, then you can switch to a virtual machine.